# How to generate a CSR for attaching SSL certificate to the site?

Tags: password, openssl, ssl

How can I generate a CSR for attaching SSL certificate to the site?
In various articles about installing SSL certificates are described different ways of generating private key and CSR. That's like two different versions: (a) `openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa: 2048 -keyout myserver.key -out server.csr` and (b) `openssl genrsa -des3 -out www.mydomain.com.key 2048`.

So -

1. How to generate a CSR and private key?
2. What is the difference between the teams generate CSR and key (a)
   and (b)?
3. Do I need to set a password when generating the CSR and key?
4. Reduces whether a site is vulnerable to attack as the password
   for the private key?

Comment: No, i dont find answer in this theme. For example, why he use  -nodes ?

Comment: For #3 and #4 you might want to check out this Q&A: http://serverfault.com/questions/329913/is-it-good-practice-to-remove-the-password-from-a-ssl-cert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL works by matching public and private keys. That is why you first must generate the key, then generate the CSR based on that key. Later, when you are using this certificate, you will find your app or service needs to know where the cert AND where the key is. You need the key to use the cert properly. In some case the key and cert can be concatenated into the same file, or imported to a java keystore.

When you see some flag like '-sha256' on the openssl req, it is telling openssl that you want to put a passphrase on this certificate (this is a very bad idea and a headache, 99% chance you do not want any passphrase. Passphrase just makes it impossible for anyone to view your resource unless they have a passphrase specifically for the certificate. This is never in use, in 7 years I have NEVER seen anyone use an ssl passphrase.

That answers your question of why. Now how do you do it:

1. openssl genrsa -out mydomain.com.key 2048

Now you just created a key of 2048 bit encryption. You need 2048 minimum now or your cert will fail audit and you have to redo it.

2. openssl req -new -key ./mydomain.com.key -out mydomain.com.csr

Now you told openssl to create a CSR based on that key you made in part 1. You now have this CSR. You can also use openssl to generate your own unsigned cert, or you can sent to a registrar to provide the cert for you (costs $).

When you get that cert, you will give directive to your app or service telling it where the key is and where the cert is. IF you use an usigned cert, it will still encrypt just as well as signed, but browsers will treat it as untrusted because capitalism (and security).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to paste you the website that really helped me when I was creating my ssl certificate and it was really useful.

[How to create a SSL certificate](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-centos-7)

Comment: I know how to install SSL certificate. But i want to know everything about the passphrase, that requested when you start CSR and key.In this site said to turn this passphrase off with -nodes. I notted it in my question in 1) 2) 3) 4)

Comment: well, you asked How can I generate a CSR for attaching SSL certificate to the site?

Comment: Maybe it was not correct qestion. But why some sites said that you need to use "openssl genrsa" ? What way is correct a) or b) ?

Comment: Look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244129/use-rsa-private-key-to-generate-public-key

Comment: Basically everything boils down to this:  if you only want to generate a key, then use openssl genrsa. if you want to generate both a key and a csr, then use openssl req -newkey rsa